# How can I use RegisterDeviceNotification without a window handle?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, usb, winusb

I'm writing a DLL library that interfaces to a USB device using winusb in VB.NET.

Since it's a DLL, I have no window, and it's possible that users of my library will also not have a window (command line apps, for instance).

The examples I've seen that detect device attach and detach all use `RegisterDeviceNotification` which requires a window handle to receive the attach/detach messages at.

How do I receive these messages directly into a function without a window to get a handle from?

Comment: You can have a window, it just doesn't have to be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently found a solution that seems more elegant than RegisterDeviceNotification for an application without a GUI.

```
    void onEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject _o = e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"] as ManagementBaseObject;

        if (_o != null)
        {
            using (ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(_o["Dependent"].ToString()))
            {
                if (mo != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (mo.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            //connected
                        }
                    }

                    catch (ManagementException ex)
                    {
                        //disconnected
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Initialize this code by calling

```
        System.Management.WqlEventQuery _q = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceOperationEvent", "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerDevice' ");
        _q.WithinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        ManagementEventWatcher _w = new ManagementEventWatcher(_q);
        _w.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(onEventArrived);
        _w.Start();
```

Also make sure to add a reference to System.Management

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't for .NET, it provides a template in C++ for the process of creating the structures necessary to handle the window callbacks, and provides a way to register a custom window handle without having a real window:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363432%28VS.85%29.aspx

> This example uses a window handle for device change notifications and
>   contains a large amount of code to support the windowing mechanisms.
>   An application intended to be installed as a Windows service would
>   contain different support code.
>
> The application will receive the WM_DEVICECHANGE message whenever a
>   USB device interface event notification is sent.
>
> The system broadcasts a set of default device change events to all
>   applications and services. You do not need to register to receive
>   these default events. For details, see the Remarks section in
>   RegisterDeviceNotification.
>
> ```
> #include <windows.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <tchar.h>
> #include <strsafe.h>
> #include <dbt.h>
>
> // This GUID is for all USB serial host PnP drivers, but you can replace it 
> // with any valid device class guid.
> GUID WceusbshGUID = { 0x25dbce51, 0x6c8f, 0x4a72, 
>                       0x8a,0x6d,0xb5,0x4c,0x2b,0x4f,0xc8,0x35 };
>
> // For informational messages and window titles
> PWSTR g_pszAppName;
>
> // Forward declarations
> void OutputMessage(HWND hOutWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
> void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);
>
> //
> // DoRegisterDeviceInterfaceToHwnd
> //
> BOOL DoRegisterDeviceInterfaceToHwnd( 
>     IN GUID InterfaceClassGuid, 
>     IN HWND hWnd,
>     OUT HDEVNOTIFY *hDeviceNotify 
> )
> // Routine Description:
> //     Registers an HWND for notification of changes in the device interfaces
> //     for the specified interface class GUID. 
>
> // Parameters:
> //     InterfaceClassGuid - The interface class GUID for the device 
> //         interfaces. 
>
> //     hWnd - Window handle to receive notifications.
>
> //     hDeviceNotify - Receives the device notification handle. On failure, 
> //         this value is NULL.
>
> // Return Value:
> //     If the function succeeds, the return value is TRUE.
> //     If the function fails, the return value is FALSE.
>
> // Note:
> //     RegisterDeviceNotification also allows a service handle be used,
> //     so a similar wrapper function to this one supporting that scenario
> //     could be made from this template.
> {
>     DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
>
>     ZeroMemory( &NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter) );
>     NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
>     NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
>     NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid;
>
>     *hDeviceNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification( 
>         hWnd,                       // events recipient
>         &NotificationFilter,        // type of device
>         DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE // type of recipient handle
>         );
>
>     if ( NULL == *hDeviceNotify ) 
>     {
>         ErrorHandler(TEXT("RegisterDeviceNotification"));
>         return FALSE;
>     }
>
>     return TRUE;
> }
>
> //
> // MessagePump
> //
> void MessagePump(
>     HWND hWnd
> )
> // Routine Description:
> //     Simple main thread message pump.
> //
>
> // Parameters:
> //     hWnd - handle to the window whose messages are being dispatched
>
> // Return Value:
> //     None.
> {
>     MSG msg; 
>     int retVal;
>
>     // Get all messages for any window that belongs to this thread,
>     // without any filtering. Potential optimization could be
>     // obtained via use of filter values if desired.
>
>     while( (retVal = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0 ) 
>     { 
>         if ( retVal == -1 )
>         {
>             ErrorHandler(TEXT("GetMessage"));
>             break;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             TranslateMessage(&msg);
>             DispatchMessage(&msg);
>         }
>     } 
> }
>
> //
> // WinProcCallback
> //
> INT_PTR WINAPI WinProcCallback(
>                               HWND hWnd,
>                               UINT message,
>                               WPARAM wParam,
>                               LPARAM lParam
>                               )
> // Routine Description:
> //     Simple Windows callback for handling messages.
> //     This is where all the work is done because the example
> //     is using a window to process messages. This logic would be handled 
> //     differently if registering a service instead of a window.
>
> // Parameters:
> //     hWnd - the window handle being registered for events.
>
> //     message - the message being interpreted.
>
> //     wParam and lParam - extended information provided to this
> //          callback by the message sender.
>
> //     For more information regarding these parameters and return value,
> //     see the documentation for WNDCLASSEX and CreateWindowEx.
> {
>     LRESULT lRet = 1;
>     static HDEVNOTIFY hDeviceNotify;
>     static HWND hEditWnd;
>     static ULONGLONG msgCount = 0;
>
>     switch (message)
>     {
>     case WM_CREATE:
>         //
>         // This is the actual registration., In this example, registration 
>         // should happen only once, at application startup when the window
>         // is created.
>         //
>         // If you were using a service, you would put this in your main code 
>         // path as part of your service initialization.
>         //
>         if ( ! DoRegisterDeviceInterfaceToHwnd(
>                         WceusbshGUID, 
>                         hWnd,
>                         &hDeviceNotify) )
>         {
>             // Terminate on failure.
>             ErrorHandler(TEXT("DoRegisterDeviceInterfaceToHwnd"));
>             ExitProcess(1);
>         }
>
>
>         //
>         // Make the child window for output.
>         //
>         hEditWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"),// predefined class 
>                                 NULL,        // no window title 
>                                 WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | 
>                                 ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 
>                                 0, 0, 0, 0,  // set size in WM_SIZE message 
>                                 hWnd,        // parent window 
>                                 (HMENU)1,    // edit control ID 
>                                 (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), 
>                                 NULL);       // pointer not needed 
>
>         if ( hEditWnd == NULL )
>         {
>             // Terminate on failure.
>             ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateWindow: Edit Control"));
>             ExitProcess(1);
>         }
>         // Add text to the window. 
>         SendMessage(hEditWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, 
>             (LPARAM)TEXT("Registered for USB device notification...\n")); 
>
>         break;
>
>     case WM_SETFOCUS: 
>         SetFocus(hEditWnd); 
>
>         break;
>
>     case WM_SIZE: 
>         // Make the edit control the size of the window's client area. 
>         MoveWindow(hEditWnd, 
>                    0, 0,                  // starting x- and y-coordinates 
>                    LOWORD(lParam),        // width of client area 
>                    HIWORD(lParam),        // height of client area 
>                    TRUE);                 // repaint window 
>
>         break;
>
>     case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
>     {
>         //
>         // This is the actual message from the interface via Windows messaging.
>         // This code includes some additional decoding for this particular device type
>         // and some common validation checks.
>         //
>         // Note that not all devices utilize these optional parameters in the same
>         // way. Refer to the extended information for your particular device type 
>         // specified by your GUID.
>         //
>         PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE b = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE) lParam;
>         TCHAR strBuff[256];
>
>         // Output some messages to the window.
>         switch (wParam)
>         {
>         case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
>             msgCount++;
>             StringCchPrintf(
>                 strBuff, 256, 
>                 TEXT("Message %d: DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL\n"), msgCount);
>             break;
>         case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
>             msgCount++;
>             StringCchPrintf(
>                 strBuff, 256, 
>                 TEXT("Message %d: DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE\n"), msgCount);
>             break;
>         case DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED:
>             msgCount++;
>             StringCchPrintf(
>                 strBuff, 256, 
>                 TEXT("Message %d: DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED\n"), msgCount);
>             break;
>         default:
>             msgCount++;
>             StringCchPrintf(
>                 strBuff, 256, 
>                 TEXT("Message %d: WM_DEVICECHANGE message received, value %d unhandled.\n"), 
>                 msgCount, wParam);
>             break;
>         }
>         OutputMessage(hEditWnd, wParam, (LPARAM)strBuff);
>     }
>             break;
>     case WM_CLOSE:
>         if ( ! UnregisterDeviceNotification(hDeviceNotify) )
>         {
>            ErrorHandler(TEXT("UnregisterDeviceNotification")); 
>         }
>         DestroyWindow(hWnd);
>         break;
>
>     case WM_DESTROY:
>         PostQuitMessage(0);
>         break;
>
>     default:
>         // Send all other messages on to the default windows handler.
>         lRet = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
>         break;
>     }
>
>     return lRet;
> }
>
> #define WND_CLASS_NAME TEXT("SampleAppWindowClass")
>
> //
> // InitWindowClass
> //
> BOOL InitWindowClass()
> // Routine Description:
> //      Simple wrapper to initialize and register a window class.
>
> // Parameters:
> //     None
>
> // Return Value:
> //     TRUE on success, FALSE on failure.
>
> // Note: 
> //     wndClass.lpfnWndProc and wndClass.lpszClassName are the
> //     important unique values used with CreateWindowEx and the
> //     Windows message pump.
> {
>     WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
>
>     wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
>     wndClass.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
>     wndClass.hInstance = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetModuleHandle(0));
>     wndClass.lpfnWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(WinProcCallback);
>     wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
>     wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
>     wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION);
>     wndClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(192,192,192));
>     wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
>     wndClass.lpszClassName = WND_CLASS_NAME;
>     wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
>     wndClass.hIconSm = wndClass.hIcon;
>
>
>     if ( ! RegisterClassEx(&wndClass) )
>     {
>         ErrorHandler(TEXT("RegisterClassEx"));
>         return FALSE;
>     }
>     return TRUE;
> }
>
> //
> // main
> //
>
> int __stdcall _tWinMain(
>                       HINSTANCE hInstanceExe, 
>                       HINSTANCE, // should not reference this parameter
>                       PTSTR lpstrCmdLine, 
>                       int nCmdShow
>                       )
> {
> //
> // To enable a console project to compile this code, set
> // Project->Properties->Linker->System->Subsystem: Windows.
> //
>
>     int nArgC = 0;
>     PWSTR* ppArgV = CommandLineToArgvW(lpstrCmdLine, &nArgC);
>     g_pszAppName = ppArgV[0];
>
>     if ( ! InitWindowClass() )
>     {
>         // InitWindowClass displays any errors
>         return -1;
>     }
>
>     // Main app window
>
>     HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
>                     WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
>                     WND_CLASS_NAME,
>                     g_pszAppName,
>                     WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // style
>                     CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 
>                     640, 480,
>                     NULL, NULL, 
>                     hInstanceExe, 
>                     NULL);
>
>     if ( hWnd == NULL )
>     {
>         ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateWindowEx: main appwindow hWnd"));
>         return -1;
>     }
>
>     // Actually draw the window.
>
>     ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
>     UpdateWindow(hWnd);
>
>     // The message pump loops until the window is destroyed.
>
>     MessagePump(hWnd);
>
>     return 1;
> }
>
> //
> // OutputMessage
> //
> void OutputMessage(
>     HWND hOutWnd, 
>     WPARAM wParam, 
>     LPARAM lParam
> )
> // Routine Description:
> //     Support routine.
> //     Send text to the output window, scrolling if necessary.
>
> // Parameters:
> //     hOutWnd - Handle to the output window.
> //     wParam  - Standard windows message code, not used.
> //     lParam  - String message to send to the window.
>
> // Return Value:
> //     None
>
> // Note:
> //     This routine assumes the output window is an edit control
> //     with vertical scrolling enabled.
>
> //     This routine has no error checking.
> {
>     LRESULT   lResult;
>     LONG      bufferLen;
>     LONG      numLines;
>     LONG      firstVis;
>
>     // Make writable and turn off redraw.
>     lResult = SendMessage(hOutWnd, EM_SETREADONLY, FALSE, 0L);
>     lResult = SendMessage(hOutWnd, WM_SETREDRAW, FALSE, 0L);
>
>     // Obtain current text length in the window.
>     bufferLen = SendMessage (hOutWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0L);
>     numLines = SendMessage (hOutWnd, EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0L);
>     firstVis = SendMessage (hOutWnd, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0L);
>     lResult = SendMessage (hOutWnd, EM_SETSEL, bufferLen, bufferLen);
>
>     // Write the new text.
>     lResult = SendMessage (hOutWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, lParam);
>
>     // See whether scrolling is necessary.
>     if (numLines > (firstVis + 1))
>     {
>         int        lineLen = 0;
>         int        lineCount = 0;
>         int        charPos;
>
>         // Find the last nonblank line.
>         numLines--;
>         while(!lineLen)
>         {
>             charPos = SendMessage(
>                 hOutWnd, EM_LINEINDEX, (WPARAM)numLines, 0L);
>             lineLen = SendMessage(
>                 hOutWnd, EM_LINELENGTH, charPos, 0L);
>             if(!lineLen)
>                 numLines--;
>         }
>         // Prevent negative value finding min.
>         lineCount = numLines - firstVis;
>         lineCount = (lineCount >= 0) ? lineCount : 0;
>
>         // Scroll the window.
>         lResult = SendMessage(
>             hOutWnd, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, (LPARAM)lineCount);
>     }
>
>     // Done, make read-only and allow redraw.
>     lResult = SendMessage(hOutWnd, WM_SETREDRAW, TRUE, 0L);
>     lResult = SendMessage(hOutWnd, EM_SETREADONLY, TRUE, 0L);
> }  
>
> //
> // ErrorHandler
> //
> void ErrorHandler(
>    LPTSTR lpszFunction
> ) 
> // Routine Description:
> //     Support routine.
> //     Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code
> //     and pop a modal alert box with usable info.
>
> // Parameters:
> //     lpszFunction - String containing the function name where 
> //     the error occurred plus any other relevant data you'd 
> //     like to appear in the output. 
>
> // Return Value:
> //     None
>
> // Note:
> //     This routine is independent of the other windowing routines
> //     in this application and can be used in a regular console
> //     application without modification.
> { 
>
>     LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
>     LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
>     DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 
>
>     FormatMessage(
>         FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
>         FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
>         FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
>         NULL,
>         dw,
>         MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
>         (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
>         0, NULL );
>
>     // Display the error message and exit the process.
>
>     lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
>         (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)
>                   + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)
>                   * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
>     StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
>         LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
>         TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
>         lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
>     MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, g_pszAppName, MB_OK); 
>
>     LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
>     LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
> }
> ```
>
> The following is an example makefile for building the previous example
>   code using nmake.exe from the SDK or Visual Studio command prompt.
>
> ```
> proj = main
>
> all: $(proj).exe
>
> # Update the object file if necessary
>
> $(proj).obj: $(proj).cpp
>   cl -c  /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -DNDEBUG -GS -D_X86_=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=_cdecl -D_MT -D_DLL -MD $*.cpp
>
> # Update the executable file if necessary
>
> $(proj).exe: $(proj).obj
>   link -release -incremental:no -nologo -subsystem:windows,5.01 $(proj).obj kernel32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib gdi32.lib shell32.lib -out:$(proj).exe
> ```